# SQL Server don't use specific index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have 2 types of queries. First one needs to take a bunch of rows by groupId and some additonal criteria (several indices are required) and second needs to take a row by id. However, first type of query, uses an index, which doesn't have groupId in it and takes a while.

At the moment I disabled (id, ...) index, but I need to turn it back on at some point.

My indices:

```
ix1_groupId_id2_id3_ival_iid
ix2_groupId_id3_id2_ival_iid
pk_id
```

I want to write something like this:

```
SELECT id2, COUNT(*)
FROM table (WITHOUT(INDEX(pk_id))
WHERE groupId=x
GROUP BY id2
```

How to tell the SQL Server, that he won't use pk_id index?

Comment: I don't see a question...

Comment: Minimally you'll need to post the table DDL and sample queries you are optimizing for.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no query hint to tell the optimizer a given index should be excluded from consideration without having to disable it; you can only tell it which indexes to consider. So, technically, you can achieve this by listing all indexes *except* the one you don't want. This can only be used for intermediate troubleshooting/testing, of course, it's not something you want embedded in a production query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not have a way to exclude an index for consideration by the query optimizer.  However, you can use the `WITH` keyword to specify which index you want.  For example, to force a query to use the index `ix1_groupId_id2_id3_ival_iid`:

```
SELECT id2, COUNT(*)
FROM table (WITH(INDEX(ix1_groupId_id2_id3_ival_iid))
WHERE groupId=x
GROUP BY id2
```

Before using an index hint, I would recommend trying to understand *why* the database is not wanting to use the index.  It may be the table is very small, so a table scan is faster than an index seek.  Or possibly the statistics are out of date on these indexes, so using the primary key appears to be faster to the optimizer.

Index hints introduce unexpected code dependencies on the schema.  If someone wanted to change the index name in the future, they may not realize this query requests the index by name, so the query will now fail until the new name is used.